# SharePoint 2010, IIS 7 and MHTML files

Tags: iis-7, sharepoint-2010, content-disposition

I have just migrated from IIS 6/ SharePoint 2007 to Windows 2008 with SharePoint 2010. We had a control that servers content with .MHT files. In SharePoint 2007 it was simply able to open it within the same window. In SharePoint 2010 it is showing a "SAVE FILE DIALOG". So, how can I fix this so that IE automatically opens it just the way it does in SharePoint 2007 without showing a "SAVE FILE AS" dialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute Force way:

Central Administration > Manage Web Applications > Select your Web Application > General Settings > Set the File Handling from "Strict" to "Permissive"

There is a better way, but I don't have the link right now (will need to look it up again tomorrow). Essentially through a PowerShell command you can whitelist file extensions rather than setting the entire web app to Permissive.